# Application.SetHighDpiMode() in .NET 8 forms applications always returns false

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-8.0, highdpi

I'm trying to test the possible options for improving the display rendering of my Forms application (before, I was using an application settings boolean to invoke (or not) SetProcessDPIAware() when starting the application. The only way I found to change the rendering  is by adding `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>xxxx</ApplicationHighDpiMode>`  in `<PropertyGroup>` of the csproj file (xxxx stands for one of the following: `DpiUnaware`, `SystemAware`, `PerMonitor`, `PerMonitorV2`, `DpiUnawareGdiScaled`).

I would like to be able to change the DPI handling programmatically, so I have added the code to do it into Program.cs:

```
        public static string DpiVal = "";

        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        <ApplicationHighDpiMode>DpiUnawareGdiScaled</ApplicationHighDpiMode>
        HighDpiMode dpi = (HighDpiMode)Properties.Settings.Default.DpiMode;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        bool status = Application.SetHighDpiMode(dpi);
        DpiVal = string.Format("SetHighDpiMode({0}) returned {1}. Current HighDpiMode: {2}.", dpi, status, Application.HighDpiMode.ToString());
        Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The contents of the string variable `DpiVal` is printed in the main form (I playing with a small test program) and I can see that `SetHighDpiMode` ALWAYS returns false and that the property `HighDpiMode` never changes.

> SetHighDpiMode(PerMonitorV2) returned false. Current HighDpiMode:
> SystemAware.

According to the documentation, false will be returned only if `HighDpiMode` is already specified in the manifest (explicitly or via `csproj` file, I presume). Yet, even if I have a default manifest file or no manifest file at all (and, of course, no `ApplicationHighDpiMode` in my `csproj` file) `SetHighDpiMode()` still returns false.
Am I doing something wrong?
Additional question: how exactly to specify `ApplicationHighDpiMode` in the manifest file? Is there some special group, like `<PropertyGroup>` in `csproj` file?

Comment: Check `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`

Comment: You have a mess there. `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();` already calls `Application.SetHighDpiMode();`, using the `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>`  you have set in the `.csproj` file (which of course you cannot have in `Program.cs`). If you have custom initialization, remove that call and add `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)`, otherwwise is missing -- `app.manifest` must specify what OS versions you're supporting. Add the manifest and uncomment what your app is meant to support